# How do you load a huggingface dataset into an Apache Beam pipeline?

Tags: stream, apache-beam, huggingface-datasets

Assuming I have a dataset which is quite large like 'oscar2301'.

I have an Apache Beam pipeline that I want to pass the HuggingFace dataset. When I try to pass the dataset to a `beam.Create`, the code tends to load the entire dataset into memory and that causes a memory out of bound error.

As known, large datasets are usually stored in a cache directory with multiple `.arrow` files.

I have thought of multiple ways to process the dataset in a way that don't overload the memory of the machine and achieves a streaming approach to save memory.

```
pipeline_args = PipelineOptions(
      runner='FlinkRunner', # running locally 
      streaming=True,
    )



with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_args) as pipeline:

    preprocessed = (pipeline
                 | beam.Create(dataset['train'])  #beam.Create(load_huggingface_data()) # parquet_files #ReadFromGenerator() #beam.Create(load_huggingface_data()) # (dataset['train'])
                 | beam.Map(prepare_oscar2301_for_c4)
                 #| beam.Map(prepare_mini_dataset_for_c4)
                   )

    # Pass preprocessed rows to rest of pipeline
    pages = preprocessed
    deduped_pages = c4_utils.remove_duplicate_text(pages)
    # Encode deduped_pages
    encoded = deduped_pages | beam.Map(lambda page: json.dumps(page.__dict__, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'))

    # Rest of pipeline
    encoded | 'Write to JSONL' >> beam.io.WriteToText('/content/output.jsonl')


    pipeline.run()
```

The code above tend to fill up almost 52GB of RAM and then runs out of memory after it gets stuck at `eam.Create(dataset['train'])` for nearly an hour.

Is there an easy way to load and process the dataset efficiently one element at a time in a streaming manner to avoid the out of memory error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to write your dataset to a file and then load the file using TextIO - https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.textio.html - that will process each line individually and won't try to load everything into memory at once. If you want to run it remotely eventually, you can upload the file to a remote filesystem (e.g. gcs) or to a custom container (seems like this run is local though).

Anything along the lines of beam.Create has to load everything into memory since its loading a list of values, so there's probably not a great way to make that work.

Comment: Also, not an answer, but if you end up doing inference with hugging face, check out the new HuggingFace model handler! https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/inference/huggingface_language_modeling.py